# slime - how to compensate probable recent changes

Tags: emacs, common-lisp, slime, sbcl

There has probably some minor/major change in how slime works, but since then I got a hard time fixing it.

I am used to a slime where, when started, there is a REPL like

```
CL-USER>
```

a `*scratch*` buffer and a tight interaction between all open buffers and the REPL.

After realizing that the Ubuntu package system wont get me anywhere anymore I installed emacs24.2 and the newest slime (cvs checkout) by myself using the given manuals.

My ~/.emacs file now looks like this:

```
;;slime-setup 
(load (expand-file-name "~/quicklisp/slime-helper.el"))
(setq inferior-lisp-program "sbcl") 
(add-to-list 'load-path "/home/simkoc/emacs/slime/") 
(require 'slime-autoloads) 
(slime-setup '(slime-fancy slime-asdf))
```

- `(slime-setup '(slime-fancy slime-asdf))` enabled the slime REPL
  buffer to be initialized.
- `(load (expand-file-name "~/quicklisp/slime-helper.el"))` enabled all
  the shortcuts I am used to, I downloaded the package via
  `(ql:quickload "quicklisp-slime-helper)`

those steps apparently fixed everything but the tight interaction between the open buffers and the REPL which is still broken.

E.g.

I am used to an interaction where typing

```
(FORMAT t "foobar~%")
```

into a buffer `*scratch*` and then using C-M-x on it, would result in the repl printing "foobar". Instead I am getting an error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function FORMAT)
  (FORMAT t "foobar~%")
  eval-region(291 312 t (lambda (ignore) (goto-char 312) (quote (FORMAT t "foobar~%"))))  ; Reading at buffer position 310
  apply(eval-region (291 312 t (lambda (ignore) (goto-char 312) (quote (FORMAT t "foobar~%")))))
  eval-defun-2()
  eval-defun(nil)
  call-interactively(eval-defun nil nil)
  recursive-edit()
```

which confuses me in two ways:

1. there is no output in the REPL as expected
2. given the (doubtful) assumption that the line contained an error: this is not the error/debug-screen I am used by slime which is supposed to look like the right top window in [this](http://common-lisp.net/project/slime/images/more-slime.png) picture.

Another symptom I got is, that c-x c-m which is supposed to expand a given macro-expression works in the *slime-repl sbcl* buffer, but in any other buffer the message "C-c RET is not defined" appears.

Does anybody else got similar problems and figured out how to fix it?

Comment: nope, this still ends in the pretty error mentioned in the question
and the repl does have the name *slime-repl sbcl*, would be quite confusing if it actually is Emacs Lisp, wouldn't it?

Comment: yeah, M-x slime-scratch opens a working buffer which works correctly, but I never used this command before and it used to work.

But apparently this is the change which confused me, as (after *scracth* didn't work) I did not try other buffers (ending with .lisp).

Please post your summed-up comments as an answer for me to accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you've used to start <kbd>M-x</kbd>`slime-scratch` as part of the SLIME mode. To have that functionality back you could do this in your .emacs file:

```
(add-hook 'slime-mode-hook 'slime-scratch)
(add-hook 'slime-repl-mode-hook 'slime-scratch)
```

I'm not sure on `slime-repl-mode-hook`, see if you really need it. Probably you need only the first one to automatically create `*slime-scratch*` buffer when SLIME starts.